# Populating a map with markers from a server

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm populating a Google map with markers, I don't get errors and my variables are getting their values but it isnt populating any markers. It just show one marker and it is my current location.

here is the code that i call when populating:

```
private void showData() {
        int count = users.length();
        for(;i<=count;i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = users.getJSONObject(i);

                maplat = Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(lat));
                maplng = Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(lng));

                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(maplat, maplng)).title("Hello Maps");

                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin));

                googleMap.addMarker(marker);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

My whole code:

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    double curLat;
    double curLng;

    double maplat;
    double maplng;



    private static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
    private static final String lat= "lat";
    private static final String lng = "lng";

    private JSONArray users = null;
    private String q;

    private static final String GET_URL = "http://testevent.site88.net/getlocation.php";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(this);

        curLat = gps.getLatitude();
        curLng = gps.getLongitude();

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    private void extractJSON(){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(q);
            users = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void showData() {
        int count = users.length();
        for(int i = 0;i<=count;i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = users.getJSONObject(i);

                maplat = Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(lat));
                maplng = Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(lng));

                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(maplat, maplng)).title("Hello Maps");

                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin));

                googleMap.addMarker(marker);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void getJSON(String url) {
        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
            ProgressDialog loading;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(MapActivity.this, "Please Wait...",null,true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                String uri = params[0];

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(uri);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                    String json;
                    while((json = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                        sb.append(json+"\n");
                    }

                    return sb.toString().trim();

                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                q=s;
                extractJSON();
                showData();
                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(curLat, curLng)).title("Hello Maps");
                // Changing marker icon
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin));
                // adding marker
                googleMap.addMarker(marker);
            }
        }
        GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
        gj.execute(url);
    }
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }



        getJSON(GET_URL);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a typo? `for(;i<=count;i++)` Where are you declaring `i`?

Comment: I declared it outside, int i = 0 ; 

EDIT: updated my code

Comment: I don't see `i` declared anywhere in the code you posted. Also, is there a reason you declared it outside?

Comment: I updated my code, sorry, i should have declared inside the loop. newbie mistakes.